# Can't get IIS URL Rewrite handle %3F in URL

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I'm using URL Rewrite to send all requests for **ci.pl** to a proxy I created (request has ci.pl then redirect to: /proxy/handler.ashx; append query string: yes). Works great. Apparently there's a really old client app that sending the following requests: http://webserver.com/ci.pl%3F4+505000+0+0+5

When it should be sending: http://myserver.com/ci.pl?4+505000+0+0+5

What ends up happening is that the **ci.pl** rule is redirecting to the proxy, but since the **?** is recieved as **%3F** no parameters are included in the redirect.

I can't update the legacy client app, so I've been trying to come up with a URL Rewrite rule to detect the **%3F** + pass along the string to the right of the **%3F**. Has anyone out there done something similar?

Here's a config that's close, but the string to the right of the **%3F** is not being passed to the proxy.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Handle %3F" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="*ci.pl%3F*" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/proxy/handler.ashx?{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Detect CI.PL">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="ci.pl" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/proxy/handler.ashx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

**Match URL**

- Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
- Using: Regular Expressions
- Pattern: `^ci\.pl(%3f|\?)(.*)`
- Ignore case: Yes

**Action**

- Action type: Redirect
- Redirect URL: http://myserver.com/ci.pl?{R:2}
- Append query string: **No**

This is how it works. The regex above mathes URIs starting with `ci.pl` followed by either `%3f` or `?` with a sequence of arbitrary characters after that. The sequence is captured and can be later referred to as `{R:2}` (2 means "the second set of parenthesis starting from the left").

For instance, if the URI is http://webserver.com/ci.pl%3F4+505000+0+0+5, then {R:1} and {R:2} will hold `%3F` and `4+505000+0+0+5` respectively, producing the result http://myserver.com/ci.pl?4+505000+0+0+5 as expected.

Here's the config file fragment:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ci" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^ci\.pl(%3f|\?)(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://myserver.com/ci.pl?{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm... The expression you suggested does not seem to resolve on my local server. When I use the URL Rewrite module to test a url (http://localhost/ci.pl%3F4+505000+0+0+5), it returns "The input data to test does not match the pattern."

Comment: While it's true the RegEx does not resolve via the URL Rewrite module **Test** dialog, it looks like the request is correctly identified and the redirect takes place. Problem solved!

Comment: @RichScannell: In this scenario the regex tries to match only the path part of the URL (i.e. everything after the last `/` and before query string, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Examples), therefore you have to enter just the following in the Test dialog: `ci.pl%3F4+505000+0+0+5`

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I didn't grasp that the "^" in the regex had that impact. I think that solves the problem.